# Guidelines / indentation lines in Google Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, indentation, devtools

Is it possible to have guidelines / indentation lines inside Google Chrome dev tools? Check attached photo.

I was looking for it for quite a long time and it's nothing there.

It would be very helpful in web development process.

[image]

Comment: guideline not showing is a bug, and have been fixed now ,see: [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1424968)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any way to display all the guidelines, but **DevTools** already does what you want to some extent:

- Select the **Elements** tab.
- Select and expand any element with a triangle and a vertical guideline will be displayed.
- Hover over any subordinate element and a second fainter guideline will be displayed.

Here's a screen shot:

[image: guidelines]

The guidelines aren't too obvious in that screen shot so I added two large red arrows to point to them, but they are easier to see on the actual screen.

I am not using any theme, so perhaps you can't see those two guidelines because of the dark theme you are using? If so, try using a different theme, or no theme at all.

Comment: my chrome (110.0) do not has it,  so strange 

Comment: @qiz_newbie I just checked my old answer above using Chrome Version 110.0.5481.78 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 10 and it is still working for me. What exactly is the problem you have?

Comment: I have post a issue in chrome forum , see more: [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1424968)

Comment: OK. I read your issue and just visited google.com using Chrome on Windows 10, as you did. It worked fine for me; a faint indentation line was displayed for any HTML element that was selected and expanded. I had run that test without using any theme (**Settings > Appearance > Theme**), so then I installed the theme "Classic Blue", and repeated the test by visiting google.com again. This time the indentation line was displayed more clearly due to the change of theme, so perhaps consider testing again using a different theme?

Comment: I try again using theme Classic Blue, but the problem still exist, I asked my 2  friends, they also have this issue  , thank you for helping me

Comment: OK. I tried changing my Windows locale and my screen resolution to see either of those changes made the indentation line disappear, but it still worked. I also tried in three other browsers that use the Chromium engine (Brave, Edge and Vivaldi) and the indentation lines worked fine in those as well. Do you still have the problem if you use Microsoft Edge instead of Chrome?

Comment: @qiz_newbie Since my answer was accepted here, and I can't reproduce your problem, consider creating a new question yourself, either on StackOverflow or SuperUser. That will attract far more attention than a comment here! Be sure to mention the issue you raised. And here are a couple more browsers closely related to Chrome that you might want to use for testing: [1] [Canary](https://google-chrome-canary.en.softonic.com/) [2] [Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium/)

Comment: I tried edge and Vivaldi, and tried canary in windows sandbox, all  no work.    you have helped me a lot, thanks!  now I am waiting for chrome official's help 

Comment: good news,guideline not showing is a bug, and have been fixed now

Comment: @qiz_newbie Great! Presumably [the nature of that bug](https://chromium.googlesource.com/devtools/devtools-frontend/+/23a3cce74f0e8efdc54210e38eab9a2e5c8b4ed3) explains why you could see the issue but I could not: _"If there is a long, wide element in the DOM tree, particularly a <style> element, the guideline for that element may disappear"_ .

Comment: you are right !